# To what extent is Java cross-compilation different from using an older compiler?

Tags: java, cross-compiling

In a project that I'm working on, we're running into [an issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8151366) that 
relates to incompatibility of a class across different versions of Java.

The suggested fix is to apply [cross-compilation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCIJIEG): Not only should we we specify the `-target` and `-source` arguments to the compiler, we should also explicitly define the correct bootstrap classpath and extension directories.

My question: What benefit does this have over simply using the compiler from the older JDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see mainly two reasons/benifits

- If you have parts of the source that uses newer language features, they cannot be compiled with the older version
- Eventually there is compiler bugs that might be fixed in newer version

Other than that I see no reason not to use the old compiler.